# Виджет поверх всех окон на Андроид

Tags: android, java, виджет

Встал вопрос о создании виджета(кнопки с надписью) которую можно было перемещать в окне приложения и которое бы всегда было поверх определенных мною окон, но при этом при переключении между активностями сохраняла бы положение из предыдущей активности(но это не слишком принципиально). Буду рад любой помощи!